# How do I change a group generator within Polar SSL?

Tags: c, cryptography, generator, polarssl

How do I properly change a group's generator in Polar SSL?

Do I just need to copy the new generator into the group, like:

```
ecp_group group;
ecp_group_init(&group);
ecp_use_known_dp(&group, POLARSSL_ECP_DP_SECP256R1);
ecp_copy(&group.G, &myNewGenerator);
```

If I just copy the new generator into my group, I get invalid results when performing a multiplication inside the group.

Do I also need to update other variables in the group, like the order (N), when I change the generator?

Comment: Always include a language tag. That will also add syntax highlighting automatically. Only valid JavaScript code snippets will run in a browser, just indicating that it is a code snippet will not make it run.